# Hough Transformation n OpenCvSharp

Tags: opencv

I am trying to use the hough transform in OpenCvSharp, but I have a lot of doubts regarding it. Can some1 pls explain or give me a sample code here? I am a bit of a novice at programming. please remember it is OpenCvSharp, so please try to help accordingly.
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but for other users who viewing this post might be useful.

You should perform Hough Transform on the [edge image](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html). you also need to define a memory storage for your Hough results. then simply use the HoughLines2/HoughCircles on your edgeImage:

```
CvSeq SeqLines;
SeqLines= edgeImage.HoughLines2(storage, HoughLinesMethod.Probabilistic, 1, Math.PI / 180, 80, 30, 10);
```

now if you want you can filter out the lines you are not interested based on their angle.